# Can I deploy web-form asp.net web application to cloud?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-applications, azure, cloud

I know such questions have already been asked many times, but I am here with my scenario. Kindly do not delete or vote to close.

1. I have an asp.net application with L2S and SQL 2008 R2 as backend
2. Using N-Layered architectured
3. Mostly normal crud operations to be performed.
4. Use of Sessions and View States
5. Manual Login / Logout(User and Roles management) , no .net Membership has been used.
6. No services used yet, might be a later part.
7. Third Party controls like Telerik or Infragistics also are in use.

I want to know:

1. Do i need to change entire application to Azure Web Application?
2. If not, is it possible to deploy it directly over the cloud , on MS or any other, as we normally do in IIS?
3. If not, Is there any third party migration tool available to make my plain old web application cloud-compatible, without affecting existing codes  ?

I want cost effective and easy to go steps?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that should be possible.  You almost certainly do NOT have to change your whole application.

- Linq2SQL is fine, I run an Azure site with L2S without any problems
- You'll have to deploy your DB to a SQL Azure database.  There are some restrictions, like all of your tables must have a primary key.  A bigger list is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336245.aspx.
  Also, when generating your SQL scripts, be sure to select SQL Azure as the database engine type: http://mooneyblog.mmdbsolutions.com/index.php/2011/09/22/generating-azure-friendly-sql-scripts/
- What do your N-layers look like?  If they are DLLs, it's fine.  If they are web services, you'll need to create web roles for them.  If they are windows services, you'll need to port them to a worker role.
- Most crud and view state and manual authentication code is fine
- For session, it depends on what you are doing (memory vs database).  But you'll have the same challenges that you would have if you deployed to any web farm
- For Telerik, I'm sure they have to have some support for Azure, and I don't think they would be doing anything crazy that would not work Azure.  You should check out their website to verify compatibility.
- Also, make sure you are not writing to the hard drive anywhere and expecting it to be there later, because instances can be started and stopped and reimaged at any point.  If you're doing that, you'll need to change it to use something else like blob storage.

I have an ongoing series of blog posts that walk through some of the steps, which should help: http://mooneyblog.mmdbsolutions.com/index.php/category/azure/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any hassles to deploy your web application into the cloud.
You don't need to convert your entire application to anything else.
After all you can just try to deploy it now with the trial subscription in Windows Azure which is free for three months.
There is a fairly big stuff of new technology in Windows Azure such as service bus, azure storage, access control service, etc. However it's not necessary to use all them right now. It's prety easy just to move the existing app into the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy it to Azure web site.
That should be easier if you don't want to use SQL Azure and cloud storage.